# Один домен - два сервера

Tags: сервер, dns, vps, домен

Планируется 2 сервера, на 1-ом - будет находится главный сайт, предлагающий услуги хостинга, на 2-ом - панель с сайтами. 
Есть ли озможность реализовать это на *одном домене* главного сайта, чтобы не надо было менять ns сервера сайтов, так как сейчас все находится на одном сервере?
Или нужно 2 домена....

Answer (score 1):

Можно настроить прокси на уровне вер-сервера. Например, если у вас nginx, то попробуйте использовать [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).
Приблизительно конфиг будет выглядеть так:

```
upstream admin_backend {
    server admin.example.com max_fails=10 fail_timeout=20s;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass admin_backend;
    }
}
```

Здесь правило location задает пересылку запроса на второй сервер если пользователь обратился по url /admin
Таким образом второй домен не требуется. Для Apache должны быть аналогичные решения.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, у тебя будет и два IP адреса?
Проще повесить панель на более другой домен.
То есть сайт будет висеть на WWW.МойДомен.local
А панели на www.ЧтоТоТам.МойДомен.local
Можно конечно извернутся, настроив редирект средствами первого web сервера при запросе WWW.МойДомен.local/ЧтоТоТам/ПофигЧто на второй но это увеличение нагрузки, а оно тебе надо?